# boost log link does not build static/shared mingw

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, mingw, static-linking

I've tried to link boost using CMake in MinGW and It does not work either in static or shared linking.
I'm using `mingw` (`x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0`)

CMakeLists.txt

```
set(Boost_ARCHITECTURE "-x64")
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:\\Boost")
set(Boost_DEBUG ON)

set(STATIC_BOOST_LINK ON)

if (STATIC_BOOST_LINK)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wl,-Bstatic")
else ()
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wl,-Bdynamic -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK")
endif ()

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS log log_setup REQUIRED)

...

include_directories(
        ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
)

target_link_libraries(
        my_proj
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Error when `STATIC_BOOST_LINK` is `ON` (stating linking):

```
undefined reference to `boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::trivial::logger::get()'
```

When `OFF`:

```
 undefined reference to `__imp__ZN5boost3log9v2_mt_nt67trivial6logger3getEv'
```

Note: from the static error I notice the `nt6` which should stand for windows, now I'm not sure if this means that the exe is on windows or the lib is compiled on windows, and if it means it should've been compiled on windows(msvc) then this maybe explains the error since I compiled it (boost) with `gcc`

### Edit:

CMake logs when `STATIC_BOOST_LINK` is `ON`

```
-- Found Boost 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS log;log_setup
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS C:/Boost/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_headers 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.76.0
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_log 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS C:/Boost/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_log 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_log dependencies: atomic;chrono;filesystem;regex;thread;headers
-- Found boost_atomic 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_atomic dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_chrono 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_chrono dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_filesystem 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_filesystem dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_regex 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_regex dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_thread 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_thread dependencies: chrono;headers
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_log_setup 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS C:/Boost/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_log_setup 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [x] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_log_setup dependencies: atomic;chrono;filesystem;log;regex;thread;headers
-- Found Boost: C:/Boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.76.0") found components: log log_setup 
-- path = E:\libs
-- install-prefix = C:/Program Files;C:/Program Files (x86);C:/Users/jamal/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-2/211.7142.21/bin/cmake/win;C:/Program Files (x86)/entrance_proj_frame_handler
-- Boost_LIBRARIES = Boost::log;Boost::log_setup
-- Found Boost 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS C:/Boost/lib/cmake)
-- Found Boost: C:/Boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.76.0")
```

When `OFF`:

```
-- Found Boost 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED COMPONENTS log;log_setup
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS C:/Boost/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_headers 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_headers-1.76.0
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_log 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS C:/Boost/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_log 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log-1.76.0/libboost_log-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_log-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_log dependencies: atomic;chrono;filesystem;regex;thread;headers
-- Found boost_atomic 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_atomic-1.76.0/libboost_atomic-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_atomic-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_atomic dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_chrono 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_chrono-1.76.0/libboost_chrono-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_chrono-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_chrono dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_filesystem 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_filesystem-1.76.0/libboost_filesystem-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_filesystem-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_filesystem dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_regex 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_regex-1.76.0/libboost_regex-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_regex-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_regex dependencies: headers
-- Found boost_thread 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_thread-1.76.0/libboost_thread-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_thread-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_thread dependencies: chrono;headers
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_log_setup 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS C:/Boost/lib/cmake)
-- Found boost_log_setup 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0
-- Boost toolset is mgw8 (GNU 8.1.0)
-- Scanning C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant*.cmake
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-d-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-s-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-sd-x64-1_76.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-shared.cmake
--   [ ] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.dll.a
--   Including C:/Boost/lib/cmake/boost_log_setup-1.76.0/libboost_log_setup-variant-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76-static.cmake
--   [x] libboost_log_setup-mgw8-mt-x64-1_76.a
-- Adding boost_log_setup dependencies: atomic;chrono;filesystem;log;regex;thread;headers
-- Found Boost: C:/Boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.76.0") found components: log log_setup 
-- path = E:\libs
-- install-prefix = C:/Program Files;C:/Program Files (x86);C:/Users/jamal/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-2/211.7142.21/bin/cmake/win;C:/Program Files (x86)/entrance_proj_frame_handler
-- Boost_LIBRARIES = Boost::log;Boost::log_setup
-- Found Boost 1.76.0 at C:/Boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0
--   Requested configuration: QUIET REQUIRED
-- BoostConfig: find_package(boost_headers 1.76.0 EXACT CONFIG REQUIRED QUIET HINTS C:/Boost/lib/cmake)
-- Found Boost: C:/Boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.76.0")
```

Comment: Do you check if `Boost_FOUND` is set? Did you try printing the contents of `Boost_LIBRARIES`? What does it say?

Comment: @AndreySemashev Yes, I have checked. I edited the question to include the logs. the `Boost_LIBRARIES` content is: `Boost::log;Boost::log_setup`

Comment: You are probably affected by a CMake [bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20638). Try to explicitly specify `boost_log_setup` and `boost_log` (in that order) instead of `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` in `target_link_libraries`. You may also have to add other dependencies of Boost.Log, such as Boost.Thread, Boost.Filesystem, etc. in the order of resolving dependencies.

Comment: @AndreySemashev
`find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread filesystem log_setup log REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(
        entrance_proj_frame_handler
        Boost::thread
        Boost::filesystem
        Boost::log_setup
        Boost::log
)`
Did't not solve the problem, error: 
`undefined reference to boost::log::v2s_mt_nt6::trivial::logger::get()`

Comment: @AndreySemashev in [boost docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/rationale/namespace_mangling.html) they talk about the `namespace` issue, and since I'm running `POSIX` and the error shows the lib is using `nt6`, I think this might be the issue, is there a way to change it from using `nt6` to `posix`?`

Comment: Don't use the synthesized CMake targets (`Boost::log`, etc), use library names (`boost_log` etc.).

Comment: > since I'm running POSIX -- You say you're using MinGW. This is a Windows target (meaning, the compiled code must use WinAPI and will run on Windows). If you want to target POSIX, you should be compiling for a POSIX system, such as Linux, for example.

Comment: `C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_log_setup
C:/PROGRA~1/MINGW-~1/X86_64~1.0-P/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lboost_log`

Comment: @AndreySemashev I meant `MingW` with `posix`  threads (`x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0`)

Comment: See how the libraries are named on your system - there are probably ABI suffixes which must be mentioned in library names in CMake. Re MinGW with pthreads, it doesn't matter, Boost.Log will still be using WinAPI and as such it will target Windows. There was some support for pthreads-win32 (which I think is what used in MinGW) in Boost.Thread, see its docs on how to configure it to use pthreads API instead of WinAPI. But that won't make Boost.Log target POSIX.